# makemigrations or migrate while server is runnig

Tags: django

I'm wondering how we can handle database migration in django while the site in production as while developing we stop the server then make changes in database then rerun the server I think it may be stupid question but I am learning by myself and can't figure it out thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to figure out? Why should you stop the server?

Comment: as in powershell i cant run python manage.py make migrations unless i stop the server then make run my commands and run the server again

Comment: How are you running your server in the first place? You should run `makemigrations` in development, then push the migration files to production. On production you update the code (including new migrations), run `migrate` and then restart the server.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can connect to the server using ssh and run commands to migrate without stopping the server and once you are done, you restart the server.

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

and then

```
python manage.py migrate
```

and then restart the server.

for example: in case of nginx and gunicorn

```
sudo service gunicorn restart
sudo service nginx restart
```